# Executing an INSERT INTO for a UNION sql using ORacle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I insert the list of values from a union statement (using Oracle)?  I have the below, but it doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO PS_Z_EXS_EMP_TBL (EMPLID) VALUES (
SELECT ee.emplid
  FROM ps_employees ee
 WHERE     ee.empl_status IN ('A', 'L')
       AND ee.emplid NOT IN (SELECT vc.emplid
                               FROM ps_vc_plan_mem vc
                              WHERE vc.vc_plan_id in ('PNC-RS','PNC-SO','PNC-ESPP'))
       AND ee.emplid IN
              (SELECT srv.emplid
                 FROM ps_Z_ADD_EMP_SRVDT srv
                WHERE     srv.emplid = ee.emplid
                      AND srv.z_serv_dt_type = 'ESP'
                      AND service_dt <= (SELECT asofdate FROM psasofdate))
UNION select EMPLID from ps_vc_plan_mem 
where vc_plan_id in ('PNC-RS','PNC-SO','PNC-ESPP')
);
```

Comment: that doesn't help :/

Comment: `INSERT INTO PS_Z_EXS_EMP_TBL 
SELECT ... UNION SELECT ...` should work for you.

Comment: there are multiple fields in PS_Z_EXS_EMP_TBL though..

Comment: Gordon's answer is what I was pointing towards, you should not use `VALUES` when using `SELECT` to insert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `values`.  Just use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO PS_Z_EXS_EMP_TBL(EMPLID) 
    SELECT ee.emplid
    FROM ps_employees ee
    WHERE  ee.empl_status IN ('A', 'L') AND
           ee.emplid NOT IN (SELECT vc.emplid
                             FROM ps_vc_plan_mem vc
                             WHERE vc.vc_plan_id in ('PNC-RS','PNC-SO','PNC-ESPP')
                            ) AND
           ee.emplid IN (SELECT srv.emplid
                         FROM ps_Z_ADD_EMP_SRVDT srv
                         WHERE srv.emplid = ee.emplid AND
                               srv.z_serv_dt_type = 'ESP'AND
                               service_dt <= (SELECT asofdate FROM psasofdate)
                        )
    UNION
    select EMPLID
    from ps_vc_plan_mem
    where vc_plan_id in ('PNC-RS','PNC-SO','PNC-ESPP');
```

Comment: that worked, the only thing is that it is telling me I have to insert something into the other columns.  how would I modify the above query to insert those values along with blank values for the other columns?

Comment: @user3586248 . . . In general, you should ask question as questions, not comments.  You might easily be able to add new columns by just adding more columns into the `insert` column list and into each `select`.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need "values" when inserting data selected from other tables. 
try the query below:

```
    ;with ins (emplid) as(
    select ee.emplid
    from ps_employees ee inner join ps_Z_Add_EMP_SRVDT srv
    ON ee.emplid=srv.emplid and srv.z_serv_dt_type='ESP' and srv.service_dt <=(select asofdate from psasofdate)
    where ee.empl_status in ('A','L')
    and not exists (select 1 from ps_vc_plan_mem vc inner join ps_employees ee2
        on ee2.emplid=vc.emplid)
    union select emplid from ps_vc_plan_mem where vc_plan_id in ('PNC-RS','PNC-SO','PNC-ESPP')
)
insert into PS_Z_EXS_EMP_TBL (EMPLID)
select emplid from t
```